# What does 착 mean when prefixed to a word?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

What does 착 mean when prefixed to a word?

- 발신정지 mean stop outgoing calls (on a mobile phone)
- 착발신정지 means stop both outgoing and incoming calls

Exactly how does 착 function in this case? Are there any other examples of when 착 can be used like this?

Comment: Note: “`발신 정지`” and “`착·발신 정지`” are the _recommended_ spacing and punctuation. This kind of word fusion is common in CJK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

착신 means *incoming call*, 발신 means *outgoing call*, and 착발신 is a combination of the two words.

착 is not actually a prefix in this case. It is a Chinese character that means to attach. Therefore, if 신 (signal) is attached (to a phone), it could mean *incoming call*.

Comment: 착신 doesn't mean incoming.

Comment: @Rathony: "incoming" was not a perfect definition, but google translate was close enough to confirm my hunch about how the word was formed and answered my own question. I did not know you were expecting a response to your comment. I already upvoted your answer, which adds a lot of useful information.  If you had worded your answer to actually answer the question asked, I would have also accepted it.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer a little bit?

Comment: @Rathony: not at all. Also if you edit your answer, I can still change it to the accepted answer.

Comment: I edited your answer and please take a look if there is anything you don't like. Also, don't worry about the acceptance. I don't contribute here for reputation points. I think your answer answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any other examples of when 착 can be used like this?

'착' is [着](http://hanja.naver.com/hanja?q=%E7%9D%80) in Hanja which has many meanings. The most important meanings are (1) to attach, (2) to wear, (3) to begin, etc. There are many words that start with this block.

> 착신: (Mail) arrival of the post or mail, (Telegraph) the receipt (of a message, a telegram)
>
> 착륙하다: To land 이륙하다: To take off.
>
> 착수하다: To begin (something)
>
> 착의(복)하다: To wear clothes (or something)
>
> 착용하다: To wear, etc.

You need to note that 착신 doesn't mean incoming. It literally means '착' = to attach + '신' = signal. In other words, literally **attachment (receiving) of signal**.